# Does the Mechromancer's gun damage bonus from anarchy apply to elemental damage?

Tags: borderlands-2

Anarchy stacks give a bonus to "gun damage". Does this bonus also apply to the elemental effects of a gun while Anarchy stacks are active?

Comment: I've actually already done the research but I can't answer my own question for a few hours.  I'll update when the time is up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just checked with my Mechromancer and the answer is no, it doesn't.  It only affects the bullet damage and not the DOT portion.  To test I shot the target dummy with a fire SMG while unspecced.  Then I got my Anarchy to 28 stacks which should be ~50% additional damage.  You can see that the bullet goes from ~40 to ~60 but the DOT ticks remain at 22-23:

Initial Test
[image: Bullet damage]
[image: DOT damage]

With 28 Anarchy Stacks
[image: Bullet damage]
[image: DOT damage]

Comment: I reward your science with an upvote.  Keep up the good work!